# How to convert sql query result in Json Object {"timestamp": value}

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

i want to use Cal-Heatmap to visualize data and my current sql result is returned as

`[ { "dateStampSecs": "1499637600", "value": "1" } ]`

but i want

`[ { "1499637600" : 1 } ]`

How do I stick them together?

I am using Codeigniter and below is my sql:

```
public function get_calData(){

        $this->db->select('unix_timestamp(STR_TO_DATE(date_start, "%Y-%m-%d")) dateStampSecs,count(*) as value');
        $this->db->from('calendar');
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();


        print json_encode($query,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dateStampSecs = array_column($query, "dateStampSecs");
$value = array_column($query, "value");
$result = array_combine($dateStampSecs, $value);
print json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$finalData='';
foreach ($query as $data){
    $finalData[][$data['dateStampSecs']]=$data['value'];
}
$finalData=json_encode($finalData);
dd($query,$finalData);
```

It will give output as

[image]

Comment: The SQL returns an array already, therefore decode doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to echo the result like following

```
echo json_encode($query);
```

exit();

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work

```
 $query = json_decode($query ,true);
    $query = [$query['dateStampSecs']=>$query['value']];
    dd(json_encode($query));`
```